# Automatically output joined fields in input layer while using spatial join

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

For example, I have two layers:

- A polygon layer `city block` with a ID field `city block index`.
- A point layer `parking lot` with a field `parking lot size`.

I want to know the total `parking lot size` for each feature in the `land use` layer, so I use the spatial join function. Here's my workflow:

1. Use `join attributes by location (summary)` to create a new temporary `joined layer` who contains a field called `parking lot size_sum`.
2. Go to the property panel of the `city block` layer and join the `parking lot size_sum` field as a new field called `joined layer_parking lot size_sum`.
3. In the `city block` layer, create a new field called `total parking lot size` .
4. Copy values from `joined layer_parking lot size_sum` and paste them into `total parking lot size`.
5. Delete the temporary `joined layer`.

All I want to do is to add a new field into the original `city block` layer by summarizing the `parking lot size` field. But I have to go through all the steps above. Is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

With the following Query, it is possible *to know the total 'parking lot size'* for each *'city block'*.

```sql
SELECT cb.*, SUM(pl."parking lot size") AS pl_sum
FROM "city block" AS cb
JOIN "parking lot" AS pl ON st_contains(cb.geometry, pl.geometry)
GROUP BY cb."city block index"
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't quite differentiate whether it's the layer name or the field name each name in your answer refers to. So I differentiate them a little bit in my question. Could you please also update your answer accordingly?

Comment: Please check updates

Comment: Thanks! It helps. Though, I guess you made a typo by typing `pl` as `pls` in the first line. Also, it seems that a virtual layer has a performance issue compared to a regular layer. It takes much more longer time to respond for each of my operations, like panning or opening the attribute table.

Comment: you are right. And yes the performance of VLs is not their best quality.